# Extending the boundaries of an object in an image and fill the enclosed region using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, curve-fitting, fill, edge-detection

I have a binary image which has an curved object, as shown below.

[image]

I am trying to extend this curved object from both ends (preferably with the same curvature) such that it reaches the x axis and then find the enclosed region, as shown below.

[image]

Could someone kindly tell me how I can do this with MATLAB?

Answer (score 1):

Given that the shapes in your images are all similar to your example, I'd do something like the following:

1. Extract the top pixel in each column of the binary image
2. Create a symmetric polynomial fitting function (a quadratic, or perhaps fourth-degree, looks like it could be good enough) that matches those top pixels
3. Create a new binary image from all pixels corresponding to values below the fitting function.

This won't match your original image exactly, but given that the binary image is incomplete in the first place I've assumed that that's not a huge problem.